# How do JavaScript's nested functions work?

Tags: javascript

I am new to the JavaScript world. Today while working with JavaScript I found the following snippet:

```
function sum (a) {  
    var sum = a;

    function f (b) {
        sum += b;

        return f;
    }

    f.toString = function () {
        return sum;
    }

    return f
}

//Calling the function
console.log(sum(4)(5));
```

Can you please help me understand when `f.toString` is executed?

Comment: Here: `console.log(sum(4)(5));`. `console.log` calls the `toString` method on functions, at least in Chrome.

Comment: Indentation would help.

Comment: In your example code f.toString() is a function that never gets executed.

Comment: It doesnt get executed!

Comment: Side note: Since you're new to JavaScript, always use semicolons (`;`) to end statement lines. It makes code far less ambiguous.

Comment: @surajck `console.log()` will call `.toString()` ...

Comment: @Pointy Can you please elaborate..

Answer (score 4):

When you pass an object to `console.log()`, it calls `.toString()` in order to print out the value.

Thus,

```
sum(4)
```

returns a function. The subsequent call to that function

```
sum(4)(5)
```

also returns a function. Then that's passed to `console.log()`, and the result in the console is

```
9
```

It should be noted that the `console` API is a pretty shaky quasi-standard, and because it's designed as a debugging aid there are some behaviors that can be confusing. In this case however it seems to simply call `.toString()` without any other "helpful" funny business. If, however, you were to just pass a simple empty object to `console.log()`, like this

```
console.log({})
```

you get (at least from Firebug in Firefox) a helpful interface to navigate the object. That's great if you're debugging something, but if you're trying to see how the language works that behavior can be confusing.

As a final note, the trick in the posted code could be extended so that the function can divulge a numeric result too by adding a `.valueOf()` method:

```
function sum (a) {  
    var sum = a;

    function f (b) {
        sum += b;

        return f;
    }

    f.toString = function () {
        return sum;
    };
    f.valueOf = function() {
        return sum;
    };

    return f;
}
```

If you do that, then you get the right answer from

```
console.log(2 * sum(4)(5))
```

Comment: If that was the case, `console.log({})` would print `"[object Object]"`.

Comment: @FelixKling no, because the function returned is explicitly given a `.toString()` method in the code posted. *edit* oh sorry; well as I noted in an amendment to the answer, you can't trust `console.log()` to do something simple.

Comment: So, here the `toString` function is replaced by a custom function. And `console.log` calls this custom function since it is internally wired to call the `toString` function? Is that correct?

Comment: My point was that it doesn't simply call `toString` on every object/value. It treats different value "types" differently.

Comment: @FelixKling yes, sorry; I agree, and I updated the answer to note that predicting what `console.log()` will do can be tricky.

Comment: I would like to point out that this is also browser-dependent behavior of the console.  IE 11 returns `[object Object]` where Chrome returns the expected result of `9`

Comment: @HowardRenollet yes, that's the sort of "helpful" behavior I was talking about :)

Comment: And also another reason why nobody should ever use IE, for anything... ever.  ;-)

Comment: @HowardRenollet The IE behavior seems to be happening because `toString()` returns a number (it's supposed to return a string). It's encountering a function with an overridden `toString()` that returns a number (yikes!) and doesn't know what to do with it. It prints out the sum if you change `toString` to use `return sum.toString()`. I would hardly call this edge case a "reason why nobody should ever use IE, for anything... ever".

Answer (score 3):

When `sum(4)(5)` is executed, `sum(4)` is executed first which returns the function `f`.

This function have access to variable `sum` (due to closure property of JavaScript functions[1]). This function does the summation and return the function `f` again.

This time `console.log` is trying to print the function `f` and hence we are explicitly defining how function should be printed by defining `f.toString` to print the sum.

**Edit**: If you are wondering why take so much pain to simply add two numbers then try the following:

```
add(2)(1)(45)(22)
```

This works because now `f` is recursively called and `sum` is updated, again due to closure property.

1: Inner functions have access to parent function's variable even after parent function has gone out of scope.